# Push Notification en backgroud IOS 10, Swift 3.0, XCode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Les comento que he migrado mi app de swift 2.3 a 3.0 y estoy trabajando con el Xcode 8. con las versiones anteriores podia capturar el payload de un push notification utilizando la funcion: didReceiveRemoteNotification.

llevo varios dias intentado capturar el payload del push notification cuando la app esta en background o incluso cerrada. 
he implementado esto:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        print("User Info = ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
```

pero parece que la segunda funcion unicamente responde cuando el app se abre desde el push.

Como puedo capturar la informacion del payloadcuando la app esta en background o cerrada?

Answer (score 2):

Cuando la app está en background puedes capturar el payload de está forma. Si la app está cerrada no hay manera de hacerlo puesto que el código no se está ejecutando.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

                   print(userInfo)

             }
```

Gracias!

Comment: Si. al final he logrado capturar la data del payload cuando el app esta en backgroud. y de la forma que me mencionas, en IOS 9 lograba capturar la informacion, pero con los cambios en IOS esto ya no es posible.

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez Encantado de haberte ayudado. Un placer :)

Answer (score 0):

En iOS 10 esa función la cumplen las extensiones de aplicación. En tu caso debes usar un Notification Service Extension. Puedes encontrar un buen resumen [acá](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/08/22/23-notifications-in-ios-10/) (en inglés)

En terminos generales, el Notification Service Extension es un binario aparte al de tu apliación, el cual se ejecuta cuando recibes la notificación push antes de que ésta se muestre. En `didReceive` obtienes un `UNNotificationRequest`, desde donde puedes obtener toda la información (en tu caso, el payload). Eso si, tiene un tiempo limitado de ejecución, y no puedes usar métodos o clases de `UIKit`.

Te dejo un ejemplo más abajo.

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var content: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        self.content = request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent


        if let theContent = self.content
        {
            /* Acá puedes procesar la información a partir del notification content 
            *
            * En este ejemplo consulto el tipo de categoría de la notificación push
            *
            */           
            if theContent.categoryIdentifier == "miCategoria"
            {
                // procesas la información y luego llamas al callback contentHandler. 
                // Tambien puedes modificar el contenido de la notifiación push antes de mostrarla

                contentHandler(theContent)
            }
            else
            {
                contentHandler(request.content)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            contentHandler(request.content)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.

        print("serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire")

        if let contentHandler = self.contentHandler , let content = self.content
        {
            contentHandler(content)
        }
    }

}
```